# Testing Angular Modules with Jasmine Unit Tests

Tags: javascript, angularjs, gruntjs, jasmine

I am using an AngularJS service in my app. I've learned that the service I've created is unreliable. For that reason, I want to build some unit tests around it. While the service works fine in my AngularJS app, I'm having problems getting it to work with Jasmine. Its like I can't load any modules. I've strip down the code to the bare bones. I do not understand what I'm doing wrong. My code looks like this:

**myService.js**

```
'use strict';
angular.module('customModule', [])
    .factory('$serviceName', [function () {    
        return {    
            isAvailable: function () {
                return true;
            }
        };
    }]
);
```

**myService.spec.js**

```
  describe('customModule', function() {
    beforeEach(function() {
        console.log('loading module...');
        module('customModule');
    });

    describe('$serviceName', function () {
        var myService = null;
        beforeEach(inject(function ($serviceName) {
            console.log('loading service...');
            myService = $serviceName;
        }));

        it('should work', function () {
            console.log('testing');
            var isAvailable = myService.isAvailable();
            console.log(isAvailable);
            expect(1 + 2).toEqual(3);
        });
    });
  })
```

**gruntfile.js**

```
'use strict';
module.exports = function (grunt) {
  grunt.initConfig({
    jasmine: {
      unitTests: {
        src: 'test/*.js',
      }
    }
  });

  require('load-grunt-tasks')(grunt);
  grunt.registerTask('default', ['jasmine:unitTests']);
};
```

My jasmine tests are running. However, its like myService.js isn't being loaded. I'm not sure how to do that. I'm also not sure how to get 'angular' (used in myService.js) in the tests either.

Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do you load you Angular application in myService.spec.js? Otherwise $serviceName is not available for dependency injection.

You should add something like this in your test file:

```
beforeEach(module('angularApp'));
```

(of course replace angularApp with the name you are using)

And it is also a good idea to use another beforeEach block to handle the dependency injection so you can use it in all tests in myService.spec.js. In total you should have something like this:

```
describe('serviceName', function () {

  beforeEach(module('angularApp'));

  var iMyService

  // Initialize the service
  beforeEach(inject(function ($serviceName) {
      iMyService = $serviceName;
  }));

  it('should check if available', function () {
    var isAvailable = iMyService.isAvailable();
    console.log(isAvailable);
    expect(1 + 2).toEqual(3);
  });
});
```

Comment: This is weird. I updated the jasmine tests to explain the problem better. customModule
  $serviceName
    - should check if available...
log: loading module...

log: testing
    × should check if available

Comment: The interesting part here is, console.log('loading service...'); is never called. I don't understand why this is happening.

Comment: I've identified that the issue is that the inject call is throwing an error. That would imply that angular-mocks.js is not being loaded properly. How should I be loading angular-mocks.js? Right now, I have it added in the vendor array associated with the grunt-contrib-jasmine task.